# TFontDialog is not displaying all fonts that are installed on the machine

Tags: windows-7, fonts, c++builder, c++builder-xe

I have a problem where the TFontDialog class is not getting all of the fonts installed on my Windows 7 machine.  For some reason XP machines does not have this problem.

It's multiple fonts that are not being displayed but the main font I'm intrested in is the MS Aerial Unicode Font.

Is there anyway I can force the TFontDialog class to look for these fonts.

I'm using C++BuilderXE.

FYI: I also tried setting device to fdScreen and the fonts still does not display properly.

Comment: What do you have assigned to the `Device` and `Options` properties? They affect which fonts can be displayed in the dialog.

Comment: Options = fdEffects and Device = fdScreen